# assign 2 letters in a subscript

Tags: assignment, subscript

Suppose I want to solve an equation for the matrix elements of $\bar{W}$:
$$\alpha W_{ba}+\beta W_{bb}=x; \alpha W_{aa}+\beta W_{ab}=y$$

Using the syntax `Subscript[W, ij]` for my matrix element (on the $i$th row and $j$ th column), I get the following message:

Set::write: Tag Times in 2 x is Protected.

Is is possible at all to write such double subscript in Mathematica?

Comment: Are you sure the error you're getting comes from the use of a double subscript?  `Subscript` objects normally work fine inside of `Solve`;  for an example, try `Solve[{\[Alpha] Subscript[W, aa] + \[Beta] Subscript[W, ab] == y}, {Subscript[W, ab]}]`.  It would help to see your code so that we can more easily track down your error.

Comment: You are right. My error came from a missing syntax in `Solve`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) rather than [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) in an equation.

I recommend that you use [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to display the output in subscripted form without subsequently having to enter subscripts.

```
Format[W[a_, b_]] := Subscript[W, StringJoin @@ ToString /@ {a, b}]

Solve[2 x == W[a, a], x][[1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html

```
Array[Subscript[a, #1, #2] &, {3, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: I am trying to solve the following simple equation: `Solve[2 x = Subscript[W, a, a], x]` and get the error message `Set::write: Tag Times in 2 x is Protected.

Solve::naqs: Subscript[W, a,a] is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.`. why is that?